# Does a battle drummer outweight a dps unit in a full balanced team?

Tags: endless-frontier

I've been playing Endless Frontier for some time now, and I always used a battle drummer in my team since I read his skill and improvement for the team.

I'm currently using a balanced team, with a battle drummer, a frost demon for the front lane and some ranged damage dealers (some with healing or control) equally discarded between magic/physical damage and between each faction.

Given that a battle drummer gives pretty nice boosts to every other team member, I was wondering :

**Does a battle drummer really outweigh a damage dealer in a team of 12?**

Your answer should be supported with real arguments, like a dps calculation.
If you go for some kinds of calculation using unit stats, you can use any unit you want as it shouldn't matter too much.